# Why do we call Functional Analysis like this?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology

Functional analysis is 'a kind of mathematical analysis' where the object of study are functions. The tool for studying functions are the operators. A specific type of operators are the functionals. My question is why do we call this subject as functional analysis, while the main role here is the operator? And if someone has any information when first is this name used and by who (because I think that the answer may have a historical background)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name *functional* was originally used to refer to functions whose arguments were functions. In this sense an operator on a vector space of functions would be a functional.

Looking around it appears that the first use of the word functional was in Jacques Hadamard's book "[Leçons sur le calcul des variations](https://archive.org/details/leonssurlecalc00hadauoft)" which translates to "Lessons in the calculus of variations," which was published in 1910.

Comment: "functional" is a known (the meaning you describe) but it is an adjective as well, as it was in the original french name "Analyse Fonctionelle".

Comment: @Smyrlis: "functional" and "fonctionelle" were also used for the topic of functional equations, this being before Frechet's and Hadamard's (and likely others in the 1910's decade) usage for what we now know as functional analysis. Thus, the word functional/fonctionelle may have been a pretty obvious choice back then.

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer.** Because it mainly deals with function spaces. These are linear spaces, the elements of which are functions, such as spaces of continuous functions, of measurable functions, Sobolev space, spaces of sequences, spaces of distributions, etc.

As opposed to calculus, where all the norms of Euclidean spaces are equivalent (and all Hausdorff topologies which respect their linear nature are also equivalent), in the case of infinite dimensional linear spaces norms are not equivalent. And Functional analysis is the "analysis" of infinite (in general) dimensional linear spaces. The most interesting examples of such spaces, and most important applications comes from function spaces.

According to the french wikipedia: *L'analyse fonctionnelle est la branche des mathématiques et plus particulièrement de l'analyse qui étudie les espaces de fonctions*.

Comment: I think that the name 'functional' is given by functionals. If it was as you say "Because it mainly deals with function spaces", than it would be function analysis. Am I right?

Comment: No. See for example the definition in the French Wikipedia: *L'analyse fonctionnelle est la branche des mathématiques et plus particulièrement de l'analyse qui étudie les espaces de fonctions.*