# linear algebra ( infinite dimensional space)

Tags: linear-algebra

Does someone have a reference (book) in linear algebra on infinite dimensional space ? I don't know anything in French Literature.

[Edit] I am sorry, i wasn't precise enough. I look for an advanced linear algebra (A complete book but wich deals indiferently with infinite/finite vector space). To give an idea i expect a book that (for exemple) would prove the existence of a base in any vector space  by Zorn Lemma.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Some more references at [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72419/a-good-book-of-functional-analysis).

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for amounts to a book a on Functional Analysis. I suggest Kreyszig.

Comment: I agree, Kreyszig is a nice introductory book to functional analysis.

Answer (score 2):

In French:

- Laurent Schwartz: Topologie générale et Analyse fonctionnelle (Hermann)
- Haïm Brézis: Analyse fonctionnelle : Théorie et Applications (Dunod).
- N. Bourbaki: Espaces vectoriels topologiques.

Comment: Bourbaki online available [here](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/archives-bourbaki/feuilleter.php?chap=2_REDAC_EVT).

Answer (score 0):

Linear algebra for infinite-dimensional vector spaces is often connected to functional analysis. If one wants to emphasise the "linear" aspect, there are books called [Linear Functional Analysis](https://books.google.at/books?id=-m3jBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=is+linear+algebra+for+infinite-dimensional+vector+spaces+necessarily+functional+analysis+?&source=bl&ots=qIim_WJ159&sig=Xeg2Mnooh6aoHXazhWNma8zv_bk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ7cuL3srKAhVC9HIKHeZsCGM4ChDoAQgtMAM#v=onepage&q=is%20linear%20algebra%20for%20infinite-dimensional%20vector%20spaces%20necessarily%20functional%20analysis%20%3F&f=false), e.g. the one by  Bryan Lynne and Martin Youngson.

The meaning of Functional Analysis is more than just linear algebra on infinite-dimensional vector spaces, e.g., see the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699270/why-do-we-call-functional-analysis-like-this).